# iOS: How to stream audio data from client to server?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

I need to send audio chunks like a stream to server while recording audio in iPhone. What is the best method to implement this? I looked at HLS. But it supports server to client streaming. I need client to server streaming. Please suggest a best method to implement audio streaming from client (iOS device) to server.

Comment: I'm not sure you can stream HLS directly from an iphone using simple means, but depending on what the server needs to to with this data, you can simply send the chunks using standard HTTP. If the file is in mp3 format, the server should be able to use it from receiving the first chunk.

Answer (score 0):

HLS is not supported from client to server. Only from server to Client.

"Streaming audio or video **to** iPhone, iPod touch, iPad, or Apple TV"

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Probably not the answer you were hoping for.